# Два подсчета в представлении MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Мне нужно составить следующее представление «Статистика по жанрам»: жанр – количество фильмов, снятых в России – количество фильмов, снятых в других странах.
Имеется таблица фильмов:[image: таблица Фильмы]

Я хочу получить представление с тремя столбцами: жанр, кол-во российских фильмов, кол-во иностранных фильмов.
Как составить представление только с количеством российских фильмов по жанрам я понимаю:

```
create view statistics
as select films.ganre, count(*) Russian_films
from films
where country = 'Russia'
group by ganre;
```

Получаю такое представление:
[image: Представление]

Я не понимаю, как добавить второй count(*) для подсчета иностранных фильмов.(Как я понимаю, не требуется подсчитывать отдельно для каждой другой страны, а нужно количество иностранных фильмов по жанрам в совокупности.) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: `select sum(country = 'Russia') ...` в where разумеется ничего не задавать

Comment: Да, я что-то забыл про функцию SUM...Спасибо, именно то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ganre, SUM(IF(country = 'Russia', 1, 0)) as `Russian`,
              SUM(IF(country <> 'Russia', 1, 0)) as `nonRussian`  
FROM films
WHERE IFNULL(country, '')<>''
GROUP BY ganre;
```

`WHERE` добавлено для игнора фильмов, в которых страна не указана.

Answer (score 0):

Можно было еще так сделать, используя UNION ALL:

```
create view stat
as select films.ganre
from films
union all
select count(*) Russian_films
from films
where country = 'Russia'
group by ganre
union all
select count(*) Foreign_films
from films
where country != 'Russia'
group by ganre;
```